# Link Google Script Editor to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script in 'script editor' called

> Clear1

to clear a selected range of cells in a sheet. When the script is run from the 'script editor' it executes and clears the chosen cells.

I have created a google drawing and allowed permissions for the script to affect the sheet, but when I click the drawing I get>

> Script function Clear1 could not be found

I cannot link a google drawing to the script.

Script is

```
function clearRange() 
{
  var Detailed = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Detailed');
  Detailed.getRange('G40:G53').clearContent()
}
```

Any thoughts? What am I missing?

Comment: but your script function is `clearRange` not `Clear1` (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that you are using the file name (Clear1) rather than the function name, in other words, instead of Clear1 use clearRange to call the script when you click the drawing.

Reference

- [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)